# Why MariaDB won't start on Fedora 20?

Tags: mysql, fedora, mariadb

Here is the error i am getting

```
mariadb.service - MariaDB database server
   Loaded: loaded (/usr/lib/systemd/system/mariadb.service; disabled)
   Active: failed (Result: exit-code) since Mon 2014-10-13 14:31:02 CEST; 10s ago
  Process: 23609 ExecStartPost=/usr/libexec/mariadb-wait-ready $MAINPID (code=exited, status=1/FAILURE)
  Process: 23608 ExecStart=/usr/bin/mysqld_safe --basedir=/usr (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
  Process: 23506 ExecStartPre=/usr/libexec/mariadb-prepare-db-dir %n (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)
 Main PID: 23608 (code=exited, status=0/SUCCESS)

Oct 13 14:30:59 localhost.localdomain mariadb-prepare-db-dir[23506]: Support MariaDB development by buying support/new features from
Oct 13 14:30:59 localhost.localdomain mariadb-prepare-db-dir[23506]: SkySQL Ab. You can contact us about this at sales@skysql.com.
Oct 13 14:30:59 localhost.localdomain mariadb-prepare-db-dir[23506]: Alternatively consider joining our community based development effort:
Oct 13 14:30:59 localhost.localdomain mariadb-prepare-db-dir[23506]: http://mariadb.com/kb/en/contributing-to-the-mariadb-project/
Oct 13 14:30:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[23608]: 141013 14:30:59 mysqld_safe Logging to '/var/log/mariadb/mariadb.log'.
Oct 13 14:30:59 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[23608]: 141013 14:30:59 mysqld_safe Starting mysqld daemon with databases from /var/lib/mysql
Oct 13 14:31:02 localhost.localdomain mysqld_safe[23608]: 141013 14:31:02 mysqld_safe mysqld from pid file /var/run/mariadb/mariadb.pid ended
Oct 13 14:31:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: mariadb.service: control process exited, code=exited status=1
Oct 13 14:31:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Failed to start MariaDB database server.
Oct 13 14:31:02 localhost.localdomain systemd[1]: Unit mariadb.service entered failed state.
```

THis is the mariadb.log file:

Im not really understanding this error, because the sock file has not been created and my server hasn't succesfully started...

```
141013 14:37:28 [ERROR] Can't start server : Bind on unix socket: Permission denied
141013 14:37:28 [ERROR] Do you already have another mysqld server running on socket: /var/run/mysql/mysql.sock ?
141013 14:37:28 [ERROR] Aborting

141013 14:37:28  InnoDB: Starting shutdown...
141013 14:37:29  InnoDB: Shutdown completed; log sequence number 1597945
141013 14:37:29 [Note] /usr/libexec/mysqld: Shutdown complete
```

I installed it fresh several times and I can't seem to figure out what the error is in the logs. I am running everything as root. Thanks.

Comment: Are you running MySQL too on the same host?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson installing mysql on fedora 20 installs mariadb. so no i have not used mysql on the same host.

Comment: solution = Xampp. especially since this is just for development purposes...